# where can i find vs2013 image library?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

[The Visual Studio Image Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246582.aspx) "contains application images that appear in Microsoft Visual Studio, Microsoft Windows, the Office system and other Microsoft software. This set of over 1,000 images can be used to create applications that look visually consistent with Microsoft software."

However, [Download the Visual Studio Image Library](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=275090) is the .zip for vs2012.

Can anyone help me locate the vs2013 version of [The Visual Studio Image Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246582.aspx)

Comment: There was no update for VS2013.  Nor is one needed, the VS2012 download works just as well in VS2013.  The name never mattered anyway.

Comment: Hans, Microsoft specifically claims that the [The Visual Studio Image Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246582.aspx) page is applicable to vs2013; if you are correct, then MS should say so imho.  FWIW, for me, assuming that there are differences between vs2012 and vs2013, then the vs2012 version will not work just as well because i am creating training materials specific to vs2013.

Comment: It sounds that you would be *way* more happy to hear this from Microsoft.  That's very possible, you can call them and you'll talk to somebody that works for them.  It just take picking up the phone, you don't need our help with that.

Comment: Hans, i wish it were that easy.  Perhaps you could suggest a phone number that would get me to someone who might be willing and able to assist me.  FWIW, in the past, when someone has screwed up something at MSDN, I've even e-mailed well known and somewhat powerful individuals at MS who have never resolved anything that i've presented in a timely fashion.  BTW, there are new graphics in vs2013, for example, the new vertical scroll bar annotation icons.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can find it here (VS2013 Image Library.zip, 285.6 MB) :
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35825

It is the same link that you originally posted, but it is now available since 5/7/2014.

Comment: much appreciated; surprisingly little difference between 2012 and 2013 ... not that i expected a huge difference, however, there were very few differences detected by WinMerge 2.14 ... one interesting difference is the file X-WorldFile(vrml,etc)_460.png which is from [Icons Used in the Development Environment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa238761%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) from Visual Studio 6.0!

Comment: there appear to be missing icons, for example "Peek Definition" ~~ "[How to: View and Edit Code by Using Peek Definition (Alt+F12)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn160178.aspx)".  "Peek Definition" is not available with vs2013 web express edition FWIW.

Comment: @gerryLowry You're welcome. Interesting. I didn't download the package yet, but according to the description, VS2012 is 19.4 MB and VS2013 is 285.6 MB, I would have expected a lot of new content for such a big step in size.

Comment: yes, i thought like you the discrepancy seemed too large; upon investigation, for those lucky enough to have a program that can process Adobe Illustrator files, there are 1486 .ai Files (332,524,754 bytes) in the 2013 ConceptIcons\AI folder that were likely used to generate most of the .png files.  The folder `_Common Elements` has be renamed `ConceptIcons`; the latter has 409 unique new .png files.